# Fast component labelling in python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I'm implementing the component labelling algorithm as in [this paper](http://www.iis.sinica.edu.tw/papers/fchang/1362-F.pdf) using python and opencv. It requires checking the input image pixel-by-pixel and perform the so-called contour tracing subroutine to assign label to the blobs of a binary image.

I manage to have it running, but it seems very slow. Profiling the code shows that the for-loop to access the pixels seems to be the bottleneck. It takes about 200ms for a 256px*256px image. Here's roughly what I do:

```
for i in image.height:
    for j in image.width:
        p = image[i, j]
            pa = image[i - 1, j]
            pb = image[i + 1, j] 
            # etc...
```

where "image" is a binary opencv image.

I wonder if there's a faster way of doing it so that it's usable also for video applications. I'm targeting something like 40-50ms running time for the same problem size, to get 20-25fps. 10-15fps would probably be acceptable as well (66-100ms running time).

Any hints, ideas what I can do is much appreciated.

Comment: Python isn't exactly a high performance language here... Try again with Java, C/C++, or something faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest OpenCV bindings for Python return numpy data types, meaning you have the full numpy arsenal at your disposal. Looping over a 2D array in numpy (with indices) is generally done with an [`ndenumerate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html), which should offer at least a little speedup (since it's a single loop optimized for N-D arrays). You could look into numpy [`vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) which would yield even more speedup, but if you need the indices of the array, then an `ndenumerate` would be what you need.

Beyond this, your best bet may be writing bottleneck operations in C.

**Update**

If it would help, I believe `scipy.ndimage.label` does exactly what you're attempting to do, and might even use the same algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Many are the posts I've seen lamenting the lack of OpenCV labeling.

As @malloc47 said, `scipy.ndimage.label` will work.  I've used it, but I wasn't happy with its performance while I was looking for the largest blob in an image.  I didn't specifically need a labeling, so I ended up using the `cv2.findContours` and `cv2.contourArea` to isolate the largest one:

```
# The [0] is because I didn't care about the hierarchy, which is the second
# return value of cv2.findContours.
contours = cv2.findContours(numpy_array,
                            mode=cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                            method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE
                            )[0]

areas = [cv2.contourArea(ctr) for ctr in contours]
max_contour = [contours[areas.index(max(areas))]]
```

This ended up being a lot faster for me than `scipy.ndimage.label` for very similar results.  As I said, this isn't exactly a labeling, but one could probably use the contour finder to give a reasonably good labeling.